# assertj eclipse assertions generator plugin

Tags: eclipse, assertj

In the past I used an assertj assertions generator plugin that I downloaded from https://joel-costigliola.github.com/assertj-eclipse-plugin/repository/. Now I get a 404 error on that library.

I also saw a citation for it at https://www.eclipse.org/setups/marketplace/?id=3377167.

That plugin helped me a lot creating custom assertions. Is it currently available at a different location?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't see that repository, but he does have a similar repository for a Maven plugin to supposedly do the same thing: https://github.com/assertj/assertj-assertions-generator-maven-plugin .

Answer (score 0):

that would be https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-eclipse-plugin but it's not maintained, I would recommend more generating assertions with the maven plugin as David M. Karr pointed out.
To be honest I would love to improve the assertions generator but don't have enough time these days, it has a few limitations (especially around generics handling) but I think it is still useful to get you started with custom assertions.